# image button disappear when i resize button (Windows Form - Visual Studio)

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio

I have problem with image in button which disappear when i resize button.

I attached bellow two pictures to illustrate my problem.

[image]

After resizing

[image]

Comment: how do you define these buttons?

Comment: This problem happen because of image layout . check for which image layout your assigned .

Comment: I insert these buttons in tablelayoutpanel.

Comment: Karthick Rajan, there is no layout in image properties. here is link to view properties of image in button : http://imgur.com/a/YUQmj

Comment: any one can help me ?